# How can I pass in bash variables and generate dynamic JSON with jq?

Tags: arrays, json, bash, variables, jq

I have a bunch of bash vars that I want to turn into JSON with a very specific format. I'm having trouble passing them in as arguments to jq and scratching my head how to then loop through the 2 arrays within jq itself. Maybe I should manually transpose the two arrays as JSON first and then pass in that JSON to jq through `--argjson`?

Here's what I've written so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

#example data                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
_assetPair=BTCUSD
_version=0.9.1
_median=103.96
_medianHex="000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005a2bc1d32419c0000"
_time=1549524531
_timeHex="000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005c5bde33"
_hash="db035aa02562167d23f657bb6f1030ba962d476f18a51c5c651b6b4b0"
_signature="51cd021f3c3edf1600aafaa81e366cd14543125dd7ec4c1da91765b0e632cfd313a3b8a291153262531e7027163ffe1239ddc9cc42815ddfcf70404a6cb5f2d71b"

#the size of the two below arrays is always equal but not known ahead of time                                                                                                                                                             
#unsure how to pass/use these in jq                                                                                                                                                                                                       
#if I pass in the elements I won't know which handle to call them with in jq                                                                                                                                                              
#maybe need some transpose magic here                                                                                                                                                                                                     
validSources=()
validPrices=()
validSources+=( "Bitfinex" "Poloniex" "Coinbase" )
validPrices+=( "104.61" "102.88" "103.96")

#Create jq input argument list                                                                                                                                                                                                            
_jqArgs=()
_jqArgs=( "--arg assetPair $_assetPair" "--arg version $_version" "--arg median $_median" "--arg median0x $_medianHex" "--arg time $_time" "--arg time0x $_timeHex" "--arg hash ${_hash:2}" "--arg signature ${_signature:2}" )
for index in ${!validSources[*]}; do
    _jqArgs+=( --arg "${validSources[index]}" "${validPrices[index]}" )
done

#sanity check                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
echo "${_jqArgs[@]}"

#generate json                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
jq -n "${_jqArgs[@]}" '{assetPair: $assetPair, version: $version, median: $median | tonumber, medianHex: $medianHex, time: $time | tonumber, timeHex: $timeHex, hash: $hash, signature: $signature}'
```

When I run the above script here's the error output I'm getting.

```
bash-5.0$ ./test.sh
--arg assetPair BTCUSD --arg version 0.9.1 --arg median 103.96 --arg median0x 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005a2bc1d32419c0000 --arg time 1549524531 --arg time0x 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005c5bde33 --arg hash 035aa02562167d23f657bb6f1030ba962d476f18a51c5c651b6b4b0 --arg signature cd021f3c3edf1600aafaa81e366cd14543125dd7ec4c1da91765b0e632cfd313a3b8a291153262531e7027163ffe1239ddc9cc42815ddfcf70404a6cb5f2d71b --arg Bitfinex 104.61 --arg Poloniex 102.88 --arg Coinbase 103.96
jq: Unknown option --arg assetPair BTCUSD
```

Ive tried adding escaped double quotes around BTCUSD when assigning it to assetPair in jqArgs but that returned the same error.

I'm expecting output like this:

```
{
   "assetPair": "BTCUSD",
   "version": "0.9.1",
   "median": 103.96,
   "medianHex: "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005a2bc1d32419c0000",
   "time": 1549524531,
   "timeHex": "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005c5bde33",
   "hash": "db035aa02562167d23f657bb6f1030ba962d476f18a51c5c651b6b4b0",
   "signature": "51cd021f3c3edf1600aafaa81e366cd14543125dd7ec4c1da91765b0e632cfd313a3b8a291153262531e7027163ffe1239ddc9cc42815ddfcf70404a6cb5f2d71b",
   "sources": {
      "Bitfinex": "104.61",
      "Coinbase: "103.96",
      "Poloniex": "102.88"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following tweaks are sufficient to get your script to run to completion normally:

1. Fix inconsistent naming

   median0x => medianHex
   time0x => timeHex
2. Change invocation (drop quotation marks)

   jq -n ${_jqArgs[@]} ...

### Handling the bash arrays

Regarding the bash arrays, I would suggest in your case reading them in separately, e.g. using the technique illustrated by the following:

```
jq -nc --argjson vs "$(printf '%s\n' "${validSources[@]}" | jq -nR '[inputs]')" '$vs'
```

With your data, this produces:

```
["Bitfinex","Poloniex","Coinbase"]
```

### Constructing `.sources`

You can then use $vs and the analogously obtained $vp to construct the object you want as `.sources`, e.g. along the lines of:

```
[$vs, $vp] | transpose | map({(.[0]): .[1]}) | add
```

Comment: Much appreciate, thank you sir. Any suggestions on how to go about adding the elements of `validPrices` and `validSources` into the `sources` JSON object?